# how to get UK datetime from a different region in Sybase ASE

Tags: sybase

I am not sure is it possible to get the current UK date time with the UK daylight saving considered as well from a different region in Sybase ASE.

Let's say I am currently locating in Sydney Australia, but I would like to get the corresponding UK date time from a server where also hosted in Sydney Australia, is it possible?

I have googled such scenario but no avail, and wondering would it be possible. I know we can easily achieve this if using programming (c#, java etc), but i would like such thing to be done in Sybase ASE.

below is what i have got to compare the local time (Sydney) with UTC time:

```
declare @HoursDifference INT
declare @Time1 BIGINT
declare @Time2 BIGINT

set @time1 = datediff(ss, '1970-01-01', getutcdate())
set @time2 = datediff(ss, '1970-01-01', getdate())
set @HoursDifference = (@time2 - @time1) / 3600
declare @StartDtTm DATETIME
declare @EndDtTm DATETIME
if (@HoursDifference = 11)
begin
  set @StartDtTm = Convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) + Convert(varchar, ' 04:30:00') 
set @EndDtTm = Convert(varchar, getdate(), 102) + Convert(varchar, ' 05:30:00') 
end
```

Comment: sounds like no ones actually knows???

Answer (score 0):

That's actually trickier than you think because the dates for daylight saving in the UK change each year so just relying on hours difference won't work. The usual way is a calendar or similar table to map dates or alternatively store all dates in UTC time format so you have global consistency. The key fact also here is that UTC time stays the same constantly - it does not change for UK daylight hours.

Also as an FYI Sybase always takes its own internal system date from the host-level system date (and timezone) on the host where the instance is running meaning you can easily have hosts in other countries running UTC/GMT so that you have consistent dates for all transactions globally easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rich.

I am aware the trickiness of such and decided to write a python program to calculate the date time between UTC, UK and Sydney Australia time, and past that time into sql, rather than trying to use sql to do such thing.

Will post my python code in here once I finished.